# update a listview with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i'm using a custom  array adapter to add data to a customized listview 
please tell me how can i update this listview and adapter
for the first time when i use `add()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` to add item to my listview array adapter it's work fine but second time i do the same but it's give me error i read somewhere that i must add a method to my adapter to handle this like addMoreItem or something 
and here is my adapter

```
public class StringArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContentSetter> {
ArrayList<ContentSetter> postList;
private int mCount = 20;
LayoutInflater myInflater;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public StringArrayAdapter(Context c , int resource  , ArrayList<ContentSetter> obj) {
    super(c , resource ,obj);
    myInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    postList = obj;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = myInflater.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mahdi);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText(postList.get(position).getPostId());
    return v;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView name;
}
```

}

Comment: Also provide the code where you do "add()" and "notifyDataSetChanged()".

Comment: It is probably because you re-instanciate the ArrayList<ContentSetter> you pass to your adapter constructor.

Comment: first time i use it in an asynctask and it's work fine second time i use a textview and a button to add item and it don't work

Comment: yes the app get's crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code you posted:

First:

Please make sure that `ArrayList<ContentSetter> obj` is not null. The super class doesn't check against null values.

Second: here

```
if (v == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    v = myInflater.inflate(Resource, null);
    holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mahdi);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
}
```

you need to call `v.setTag(holder)`, in the if condition, after you initialized the `holder`.

```
if (v == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    v = myInflater.inflate(Resource, null);
    holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mahdi);
    v.setTag(holder);
}
```

Third

if `getPostId()` is returning an `int`, you should wrap is the return value around `String.valueOf`. The overloaded method of `setText` that takes  an int try to look up a localized string, and throws an Exception if a match can't be found

Comment: wow thanks man finally it's worked but i got another problem when when i press the button previous data that i got using asynctask getting remove